# Get multiple maximum values from a mx2 matrix

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix of dimension mx2. What I need is a mx1 matrix such that each element of the mx1 matrix is taken as the maximum value from each 1x2 row of the mx2 matrix. I can do by iteration I know but is there a direct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it directly. the `max` function in matlab lets you specify the dimension over which you want to take max on:

```
max(data_m_by_two, [], 2)
```

should give you what you want, the `2` in there says you want to take max over the second dimension of the matrix, which is over the columns.

Comment: @user34790: make sure you don't forget the empty brackets, otherwise you will take the maximum of your data and 2.